# How to calculate if an aspect ratio is wide or not?

Tags: aspect-ratio

I can see most phone cameras put at the side of the resolution if its wide. So its easy to see sizes with the text such as: *2560x1536* **(wide)**

I know as standard general knowledge that 16:9 is clasified as "**wide**".
My question is how can I calculate if a resolution is "wide" or not?

I know already how to get the aspect ratio such as 16:9, 4:3, etc. But not idea how to then decide if an aspect ratio is wide,

So for example why are these classified as wide?

2048x1232 = 128:77

1600x960 = 5:3

Answer (score 1):

If the first part of the aspect ratio divided by the second part is > 1.3334 then it is considered wide.

So 4:3 is 4/3 = 1.333, not wide.

16:9 is 16/9 = 1.777, wide

Comment: The exact cutoff point probably depends on your context. Would 1.5 really be wide?

Comment: @mark True, 3:2 is right in the middle. Sometimes it is considered wide, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

```
16/9 = 1,77
5/3 = 1,66
128/77 = 1,66
```

If you define 16:9 as "wide", then 5/3 and 128/77 are not wide because they have a smaller aspect ratio.
Yet, I believe the assumption for wide is 1,30 somewhere, so then 5:3 and 128:77 would be wide